# Using std:: lower_bound

Tags: c++

```
// lower_bound/upper_bound example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::lower_bound, std::upper_bound,    std::sort
#include <vector>       // std::vector

int main () {
int myints[] = {10,20,30,30,20,10,10,20};
std::vector<int> v(myints,myints+8);           // 10 20 30 30 20 10 10 20

std::sort (v.begin(), v.end());                // 10 10 10 20 20 20 30 30

std::vector<int>::iterator low,up;
low=std::lower_bound (v.begin(), v.end(), 20); //          ^
up= std::upper_bound (v.begin(), v.end(), 20); //                   ^

std::cout << "lower_bound at position " << (low- v.begin()) << '\n';
std::cout << "upper_bound at position " << (up - v.begin()) << '\n';

return 0;
}
```

In this code can somebody please explain why we need to do (low - v.begin()) and (up - v.begin()) on the third and fourth lines from the bottom.

If I do

```
cout << low << endl;
```

I get the follwoing error which I dont understand

```
  cannot bind ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream&&’
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*low *is an iterator as you declared. It holds the memory address that generates by your PC and you don't need any memory address to return . By writing

```
low- v.begin()
```

You make a command to your program to return the actual position of your searching query as an answer.

That's why it returns a value the

```
Address Position - Beginning of the Vector Position
```

Suppose your vector starting memory address is FFF1 and your searching value is at FFF8 ... Then it return FFF8 - FFF1 = 7 .. ( Example is just to illustrate )

That's how I understand .

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I needed to understand. Sorry for the petty question though.

Answer (score 2):

The two subtractions are calculating the offset of the elements found at the positions `low` and `up` in the vector by calculating the delta between the iterator `v.begin()` and the iterators `low` and `up`, respectively. To make this code clearer, it probably would have been better to use [std::distance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance).

When you tried to use `cout << low << endl;` you were trying to print out the value of the iterator. That's very different. Oh, and you're missing the std:: namespace reference around `cout` and `endl`.

Comment: Thanks. I got it now.